# Looping through every character in user input

Tags: c++, get

Major beginner here, how can I loop through every character in a user-input using:

```
get(char& c)
```

I'd like to use it in a loop to do something with each character (incuding whitespace), but I can't get it to work at the moment.

If you can do so, please provide sample code.

Thanks

Here is what I have right now:

```
for (char& c : cin.get(char& c)) { 
    cout << c;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far and we can help you out with your actual issue(s)?

Comment: You can just iterate over the `std::string`. Operator `[]` should give characters at each index.

Comment: No I need to use the get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would write it like this;

```
std::string s;
while(std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
    for(char c : s) {
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

Although don't forget to account for the '\n' delimeter should you want to keep it. Note that unless you turn of terminal buffering (non standard), you will only get input on a line by line basis anyway.

Note, you can end the loop by signalling an end of file. On linux the user must press Ctrl + d.

Else you can add some logic to the loop and break. For example

```
if(c == 'q') break;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a loop on the entered character, until the entered character is `enter` (Ascii code 13)

```
char c;

while ((intVal = (int)cin.get(c)) != 13){
...do processing on the character 'c'
}
```

or use

```
char c;
    int intVal=0;

    while ((c = cin.get()) != 13){
    ...do processing on the character 'c'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Though now i get: 'get' was not declared in this scope

Comment: then use cin.get instead of get